# Xtext project creation concerns

Tags: configuration, xtext

Before I begin I must admit that I am new to Xtext and the designing of DSLs. Some of my questions on this matter may be somewhat "less than intelligent".

I have created an Xtext project using the IDE, and I am simultaneously using one of the sample projects provided with Xtext as a guide to what I need to do in my language. I am seeing a lot of warnings that are making me nervous.

Apparently, when the development environment creates a new project, it somehow configures that project to use the Java 5 libraries. I am using Java 6, and as a result I get warnings saying that my project is configured for Java 5 and there is no Java 5 on my system (which there isn't!).

I have tried altering the build path so that it uses Java 6 libraries, but this generates a number of other warnings -- including warnings that the Java 6referenced in my manifest.mf file is invalid!

Then there are the "plugin.xml" warnings. Apparently, the build.properties file references a file called "plugin.xml" which is not created when the IDE creates the project. I have no idea whether or not this file is important enough to create, and I have no idea what should go into it.

Frankly, I hate warnings. Warnings tend to lead to future problems in what I produce. I like clean compiles and clean deployments. I would like to eliminate these warnings, before they start screwing me up down the road (like putting in Java6 classes that would break in a Java5 library).

Has anyone been able to eliminate these warnings reliably? Please advise.

Answer (score 1):

For the JDK warning, you simply switch in the Manifest.MF to a target environment matching your preferred JDK ('JavaSE-1.6 ' in your case).

The warning regarding the missing plugin.xml will be gone as soon as you have run the grammar generator the first time, as it will produce such a file.